# Jenkins: Environment separation during executing Jenkins2 Declarative Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins server running on a Virtual Machine and has 2 agents configured.

I am trying to execute the following stages using Jenkins Pipeline as a code in Continuous Delivery format.

Build -> Unit Test -> Containerize -> Deploy to Dev Kubernetes Cluster -> Carry out minimal testing -> Deploy to Staged Kubernetes Cluster -> Integration Tests -> Deploy to UAT

I have 2 microservices in using different repositories.

I have a scenario where My service 1 deploys kubernetes artifacts in Dev Kubernetes clusters and simultaneously my Service 2 deploys kubernetes artifacts on Staged cluster.

Can I isolate the contexts in anyways so that the kubernetes clusters information is not mixed between 2 pipelines?

Comment: Clarification on what the problem you are encountering is required. Two jobs executing already get their own workspaces and Shell environments.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to set two kubernetes context through 2 different jobs. Does this mean that if I set a context that points to development environment from one job will not affect the context in another job?

Comment: I do not have much experience with Kube but it shouldn't if its being set in the job. Only if it was a global setting or tool config would it apply. 
Also ensure, before you begin and after you finish that you are deleteDir() the workspace. You want to be nice and clean to avoid coming into a dirty area.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the scenario and post my findings.